# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django>=2.0

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm using python2 and django vesrion 1.8.13. When I tried to install django-urls got this error.

```
  Using cached django_urls-1.0.3.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django>=2.0 (from django-urls) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django>=2.0 (from django-urls)
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: [`django-urls`](https://pypi.org/project/django-urls/) isn't a commonly used Django package. Are you sure you want to install it? Or did you try to install it to fix an import error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that django-urls has *always* required Django 2+

To resolve it you either need to upgrade your django version, or not use django-urls.

Side note: for other packages on pypi that have been around for longer - it is often possible to install an old version that supports your python/django version. It is likey that `pip` has been doing this for you. This is not the case for django-urls.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is EOL, you shouldn't use it anymore as it won't receive any further security updates and the ecosystem for it is finally vanishing (besides, it's pretty outdated regarding core features and performance).

Django 2+ ist Python3 only, that's why you can't satisfy the package requirements.

Comment: It's not drum-beating, it's pointing out a matter of fact. Everyone who still uses python <3.5 connected to the web and who is not manually back-porting security patches and doing their own compiles is endangering his visitors and customers.

Comment: But I agree, I should have pointed out a more direct solution :)